# Problema con placeholder de ui-select

Tags: angularjs, select, div, entrada

Al parecer cuando ubico un ui-select dentro de muchos elementos , el placeholder de este elemento obtiene un width:10px (no sé porque), lo cual es un problema porque aparte de verse mal dicho elemento, sólo puede ser seleccionado dando dando el click justo donde se ve la letra en la orilla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí ejemplo del código usando angularjs:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="arabicaEditCtrl as $ctrl">    
    <div ng-show="!$ctrl.loading">
       <form role="form" class="form-signin form" ng-cloak>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
               <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                          <label class="control-label" for="totalAcidez" style="color:#1abb9c;">Total acidez (+):</label>
                          <ui-select name="labs" ng-model="$ctrl.model.totalAcidez" theme="bootstrap">
                              <ui-select-match placeholder="Escoja valor">
                                  {{$select.selected}}
                              </ui-select-match>
                              <ui-select-choices repeat="item in $ctrl.collections.values track by $index">
                                  <div ng-bind="item"></div>
                              </ui-select-choices>
                          </ui-select>
                      </div>
            </div>
       </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Sólo si quito el `<div ng-show="!$ctrl.loading">` se muestra de forma correcta.

Answer (score 1):

Al parecer no es una falla que ocurre por estar contenido en varios divs, sino que ocurre cuando el elemento ui-select llega a  se ocultado de alguna forma. Para solucionarlo incluir en un css:

```
 .ui-select-multiple.ui-select-bootstrap > div > input.ui-select-search {
    width:auto !important;
}
```